# How to execute shell commands in ansible containing special characters

Tags: ansible

How to execute shell commands in ansible along with special characters?

```
---
 - name: Displaying the ORACLE_HOME
   hosts: "{{ hostname }}"
   tasks:
   - name:
     shell: echo $ORACLE_HOME
```

I want the output of echo $ORACLE_HOME

Comment: What errors are you getting? Your exact playbook is working for me as it is, I'm just checking "echo $SHELL" and it gave me the output.

Comment: @Pacifist_AWS, I did not get any error in this. But output also i am not able get

Comment: You will not get any output from such a command in ansible unless your [register](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) the task result and [debug](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html) it or run `ansible-playbook` in verbose (`-vvv`) mode.

Comment: @Zeitounator, still I am not getting output

Answer (score 0):

You need to write something like this :

```
---
 - name: Displaying the ORACLE_HOME
   hosts: "{{ hostname }}"
   tasks:
   - name:
     shell: echo $ORACLE_HOME
     register: var

   - debug: msg="{{ var }}"
```

or

you can use the registered variable as `var.stdout` in your code.

As per your comment, use below command to use the shell variable in your playbook :

```
shell: source <Absolute-Path>/.bash_profile && echo $ORACLE_HOME
```

Comment: Before registering the output i did not get any output from that command. 

Its conflicting the underscore _ special character.

how to overcome it , can you please help

Comment: @Raghu Updated the answer. Please check if it works.

Comment: I have one more question @ Pacifist_AWS . Will you please give a solution to me ?

Comment: @Raghu I can try.

Comment: @Raghu No Problem. If you feel, accept the solution as a valid answer as it help others to rely upon the solution.

Comment: Question is 

1. I have mysql database statement, In which i have to give path for backup dynamically in ansible-playbook but it was not accepting. It's accepting statistically.

query is ::

backup database dbname to disk ="{{ path }}"

while executing the playbook path='C:\backup\file.bak'

Comment: @Raghu You need to provide me the piece of code, as I might not be able to understand the scenario completely.

Comment: Source code
---------------

---
 - hosts: windows
   tasks:
   - name: Finding SQL Version
     local_action:
      module: mssql_query
      login_host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      port: 1433
      login_user: 'admin'
      login_password: 'Atlas_123'
      db: ansible
      query: backup database ansible to disk="{{ die }}"
      autocommit: True
     register: version
   - name: printing output
     debug:
      var: version

Comment: i want Execution like this ...

ansible-playbook SQLversion.yml --extra-vars="die='C:\backup\file.bak'

Comment: First of all, Your command should be : ansible-playbook SQLversion.yml -e "die='C:\backup\file.bak'". Your debug line should be debug: var="{{ version }}"

Comment: How to store ansible logs while executing the playbooks ?

Comment: @Raghu if you are running through terminal then just add " >> a.txt " at the end and it will flush all the logs to a.txt

Comment: Hai @Pacifist_AWS ,

How to change user password in linux through the ansible playbook ?

can you please explain ?